# Changing date format from MySQL in php

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, this code : `<?php echo $user->last_login?>` is showing this date format `YYYY-MM-DD` from MySQL. How do i change it to this format `DD-MM-YYYY`?

Thanks.

Edit : Problem solved. `$date = new DateTime($user->last_login);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Thanks guys!

Comment: Did this `echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($user->last_login));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
date(d-m-Y", strtotime($user->last_login));
```

Or this:

```
$date = new DateTime($user->last_login);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

Or use Carbon (http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $user->last_login)->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually @frayne-konok was close. You'll need to do

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($user->last_login));
```

See the PHP docs for more date formatting codes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php